# Busy indicator race condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, race-condition

I have the following (javascript/jquery) code to show a busy indicator (after a delay) while an image is loading:

```
function imgUpdate(arg) {
    var loaded = false;

    $("#image").one("load", function(){
        loaded = true;
        $("#busyIndicator").hide();
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!loaded) {
            $("#busyIndicator").show();
        }
    }, 250);

    $("#image")[0].src = arg;
}
```

Sometimes, the indicator comes up and stays up. How is this possible if the browser's javascript engine is single-threaded? (This is on Firefox 3, by the way.)

One note: this seems to happen when the image being loaded is already cached.

Another note: if I log to my firebug console, all of the lines in imgUpdate are executed, but a log message inside the onload handler never prints on subsequent calls to imgUpdate.

Comment: so basically you're trying to implement a "loading progress" with jquery?

Comment: Yes - one that doesn't show if the image loads quickly.

Comment: There is no race condition - JavaScript is single-threaded. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue if you display the indicator right away, in the same stack frame, without using setTimeout()?

Comment: @DrJokepu: Yes - it still happens in that case.

Also, I added a line of extra information to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Keep in mind that the HTML 4.01 / XHTML 1.0 / XHTML 1.1 standards do not support the onload event on images. If you don't believe me, check it out: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the image's src tag seems to fix the problem:

```
function imgUpdate(arg) {
    var loaded = false;

    $("#image").one("load", function(){
        loaded = true;
        $("#busyIndicator").hide();
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!loaded) {
            $("#busyIndicator").show();
        }
    }, 250);

    $("#image")[0].src = "";
    $("#image")[0].src = arg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm hard pressed to replicate this.

Here is the implementation of what you're doing:

A version using caching:
http://jsbin.com/uwuho

A version with caching being prevented: (uses parameter to avoid caching)
http://jsbin.com/oguvi

Hit F5/Ctrl-F5 to see it go. (in particular with the version which prevents caching)

With or without caching neither version is doing what you'd described.

Your problem *probably* lies elsewhere.

Comment: I couldn't replicate it using your code, either. But if the problem were something else, the fix I posted (in an answer here) doesn't seem like it would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any other javascript on the page that breaks?  If so, this may not be a race condition -- JS could simply stop executing before the busyIndicator is hidden again...

Comment: Nope - firebug shows that there aren't any errors and that an unrelated ajax request is still executing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clear the timeout in your callback so that it won't fire if the image is loaded.

```
var timer = null;
function imgUpdate(arg) {
    var loaded = false;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#busyIndicator").show();
        timer = null;
    }, 250);        
    $("#image").one("load", function(){
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
        $("#busyIndicator").hide();
    });
    $("#image")[0].src = arg;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still exhibits the same problem. I updated the last line of my question with some additional info.